# When I use left window key + e in konsole it prins 'se'

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb, kde4, konsole

I was trying to change my keyboard layout and when I tried it in the konsole, I saw that konsole interprets it rather oddly. Win + E executes some hostnames and prints "se" on the prompt. With other keys like T or R  the hostnames are not shown but "st" respective "sr" are added to the prompt. Why this happens and how I can make konsole behave more like xterm (where everything works).

Comment: Run the program `xev` from a terminal. Focus the xev window and press the Win key. A paragraph starting with `KeyPress event,` appears in the terminal. Copy-pase it into your question.